# Using python to put if and elif statements under input or similiar

Tags: python

Im learning python off of https://sololearn.com (Don't know if thats a good place to learn python or not but it seems pretty well) and Im wondering is their some kind of similar to (This is a just an example btw not literate)

```
x = input("What is your age\?")
if x > 18:
print("You are welcome")
elif x < 18:
print("You are underaged, try again later")
```

If I try running this in IDLE it seems if gives an error as invalid syntax. Any thoughts?

Comment: Indent the print statements.

Comment: @DYZ The indenting is probably the issue; I wouldn't recommend fixing that for OP in case that is the problem

Comment: @HyperNeutrino Probably.

Answer (score 1):

You may be trying to compare a string with a number here:

```
if x > 18:
```

To solve this, try this:

```
x = int(input("What is your age\?"))
if x > 18:
   print("You are welcome")
elif x < 18:
    print("You are underaged, try again later")
```

This will ensure the number you take from input is always an integer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Indentation

Python cares about indentation. So, indent the blocks inside of the `if` and `else` statements (same goes for all block statements).

#### Escaping things

`?` doesn't need to be escaped, so don't escape it. `\\` needs to be escaped in a string literal, as well as `"` and `'` if you are using a single one of those quotes (triple-quote string literals don't require that unless you have 3 in a row, in which case escaping one suffices; you don't have to escape `'` in a `""` literal and vice versa)

#### Input

If you are using Python 2, great. If you are using Python 3, `input` gives a string, so do `x = int(input("..."))` to convert to an int.

#### If... Else

Unless you have more statements after the last `elif`, just use `else`. Also, what happens when `x == 18`? `x < 18` is false as well as `x > 18` so nothing will happen. No message for 18 year old users... :P

So, the final code would look like this:

```
x = input("What is your age?") # replace with `int(input(...))` in Python 3
if x > 18:
    print("You are welcome")
else:
    print("You are underaged, try again later")
```

Answer (score 0):

The code above seems fine but it depends on the python version as well. In python 2.x, input() tries to evaluate the user input to appropriate data type but in python 3.x input() works like raw_input() in python 2.x, ie. it takes in string and keeps it that way. So if you try to compare a string with an int checking for a condition, it will fail.

Also please keep in mind that indentation is very important which if not in proper order can cause errors. Try to use either  or  but NOT both to keep things simple.

Comment: Passing incorrectly typed data to a function is not a syntax error.